# Add site search to user browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, search

I have a website and I want to add my site search to the user browser once they visit my site.

Sample site searches

[image]

When user searches

[image]

Thanks so much

Comment: Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=site+search+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Search Website From Address Bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50869494/how-to-search-website-from-address-bar)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50869851/9226464) answer, I think it should put you on the right track!